# How to convert an IBAN to an Integer?

Tags: integer, radix, bignum, iban, base36

Note, this is not about using libraries or any specific programming language. I just want to understand the following concept, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN), *Validating the IBAN*:

> Example (fictitious United Kingdom bank, sort code 12-34-56, account number 98765432):
>
> - IBAN:
>
>   ```
>      GB82 WEST 1234 5698 7654 32
>   ```
> - Rearrange:
>
>   ```
>      W E S T12345698765432 G B82
>   ```
> - **Convert to integer**:
>
>   ```
>     3214282912345698765432161182
>   ```
> - Compute remainder:
>
>   ```
>     3214282912345698765432161182  mod 97 = 1
>   ```

The bold step is causing me headache. I'm assuming the IBAN is alphanumeric, i.e., Base-36 encoded (10 numbers, 26 letters).

Now, when I convert the base-36 to base-10 (this is how I understand this step), my result is way off. Here, for example, in Ruby:

```
 $ irb
irb(main):001:0> "WEST12345698765432GB82".to_i(36)
=> 15597194993925618867946544653683410
```

Now, please, someone enlighten me, what is really meant by *convert to integer*?

Comment: Yes. I need the modulo for checksum / validation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! The formatting on Wikipedia gave me a hint: It's not a single, whole, big number but each character has to be converted on its own:

```
"WEST12345698765432GB82".split("").each do |c| 
  print c.to_i(36)
end
```

Result:

```
3214282912345698765432161182
=> ["W", "E", "S", "T", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "G", "B", "8", "2"]
```

Note, the `W` is the 32th integer in Base-36:

```
"W".to_i(36)
=> 32
```

And so on.